# Can I attach a kitchen vent and a dryer vent to the same exhaust?

Tags: kitchens, vent, dryer

I currently have a dryer attached to an exhaust vent with flexible tubing; this flexible tubing is in severe need of repair.  That is (I hope) easy enough, and is not the crux of my question.

The problem is that my kitchen vent (above an electric stove), rather than exhausting anywhere sane, exhausts *into* the laundry room.  This, to me, is a terrible idea (but I am hardly a ventilations expert), and I would like to remedy it.

[image: The vents, such as they are]

Since I'll be going to the supply store and working to replace/repair the damaged tubing *anyway*, I wonder if it's possible to attach the kitchen vent *and* the dryer vent to the same exhaust (rather than running a second duct and cutting a new exhaust hole in the wall).  I'm thinking it would be easy (and cheap) enough to just attach a T- or Y-joint (again, note, I am hardly a ventilations expert), but I don't know if that's a viable and/or safe option.

So the question lies thus: What sort of considerations/parts do I need to do this sort of renovation, and — given that I am hardly a ventilations expert — is it something that can be safely (and reasonably) done without professional help?

Comment: I am almost certain that plastic tubing is not rated for use as a stove exhaust, but either way I would not use it there (or anywhere, to be honest). Like @BMitch says, use smooth, rigid tubing as much as possible (better airflow, and less chance for buildup to accumulate), and only use the (metallic) flex tube for the final hookups, if needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're mixing grease with lint, which is only going to make a mess and clog up in no time. You could also create a situation where dryer exhaust goes back into your house instead of outside, causing excessive humidity and a mold/mildew risk. The workaround for that would be to install dampers, but those would likely get jammed with the grease/lint combination. And that's assuming that this would be within code, which I suspect it isn't, or every builder would cut the corner. So, in short, my suggestion is that you don't even consider joining the two.

Also, a suggestion, only use flex pipe for the final hookup to each device, and cut away any excess flex tubing. The rest should be rigid metal venting for durability and to give you the best airflow.